# How to do linting with Questasim?

Tags: verilog, hal, cadence, questasim

I was using linting tool HAL from Cadence. Now I have to use Questasim. But I don't know about the tools or switch that I can use for linting.

- ***Is there any tool*** from Mentor(Questaism) like HAL from Cadence (HAL is a separate tool for linting only).

**OR**

- ***Is there any switch*** that I have to use to enable Questasim for linting with any of these "Vlog | Vopt| Vsim| Qverilog".

Answer (score 0):

Questasim Perform lint checking at lower level only,

```
-lint              Perform lint-style checks
```

i.e. vlog -lint

Better to go for standalone tool for linting.